# google drive integration for upload photo from app to google drive in ios (swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I need tutorial for upload camera capture photo from my application upload directly to google drive.
Currently using https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart?ver=swift
tutorial but not getting proper solution,Can any one help me how can i add all libraries in my project using cocoapods, In tutorial only display below code run in terminal, but how can i get all libraries?

```
cat << EOF > Podfile &&
platform :ios, '7.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'QuickstartApp' do
    pod 'GoogleAPIClient/Drive', '~> 1.0.2'
    pod 'GTMOAuth2', '~> 1.1.0'
EOF
pod install &&
open QuickstartApp.xcworkspace
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your question I can say you are very new to cocoapods.
The code you presented creates a pod file witch shows cocoapods what framework it has to download. If you have it installed running `pod install` should be enough, if not [this](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html) will help.